# Issue with javascript in IE - disable field

Tags: javascript, html-table

I am beginner in Javascript and I have a problem with IE - where it doesn't work correctly but in chrome this code works. Could somebody help me?

In IE 8, and problem is in change IncommingOrOutcomming and TypeOfMessage when is value IncommingOrOutcomming = P and TypeOfMessage 10, the field Input isn't disabled.

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html" prefix="h"%>
 <%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core" prefix="f"%>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script> <script>

        function DAP() {
        var com1 = document.getElementById('form1:Input'); // It represent string input field 
        var com2 = document.getElementById('form1:TypeOfMessage');
        var com3 = document.forms[0].elements['form1:IncommingOrOutcomming'];

        if (com2.value == '10' && com3.value == 'P') {
        com1.disabled=true;
        }
    </script>    

        <table>
        <tr>                        
        <td><h:outputText value="#{bundle.txt_zpr}"></h:outputText></td>
        <td><h:selectOneRadio id="IncommingOrOutcomming" value="#{Bean.message}"onchange="DAP();" > 
        <f:selectItem id="item1" itemLabel="#{bundle.txt_prichotzi}" itemValue="P" />
        <f:selectItem id="item2" itemLabel="#{bundle.txt_odchozi}" itemValue="O" />
        </h:selectOneRadio></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td><h:outputText value="#{bundle.txt_zprava_typ}"></h:outputText></td>
        <td><h:selectOneMenu id="TypeOfMessage" value="#{Bean.typeOfMessage}" onchange="DAP();" >
        <f:selectItems value="#{HledejBean.typZpr}" />
        </h:selectOneMenu></td>
        </tr>
        </table>
```

Comment: `com1.disabled='disabled';`?

Comment: if you want a specific answer, please be more specific in your question. what version of IE? what kind of issue? what do you get? any error? what are the h: preffixes in your html tags? the disabled = true; works perfectly fine in IE 11. please provide a jsfiddle.net example where you see the issue.

Comment: @ps2goat—the *disabled* attribute is boolean, so the property should be set to either `true` or `false`. Using a string to set the value may produce unexpected results (e.g. `''` -> `false`, `'false'` -> `true`).

Comment: @RobG disabled="disabled" works perfectly fine too.

Comment: @Banana - "disabled" is converted to true using the JavaScript falsey rules

Comment: @attila that doesnt contradict my statement. workes perfectly fine. and besides, html accepts disabled="disabled" as well.

Comment: @Banana—HTML **allows** a value for boolean attributes to satisfy HTML authoring tools that require XML syntax where attributes must have values. The actual value is irrelevant. Note `element.disabled = '';` will set the property to *false*, but in the HTML `disabled=""` will set it to true. So please do not encourage the use of strings for setting boolean values.

Comment: Would be great if you guys both actually pay attention . Op has an issue with IE not with string values, in my original comment i didnt say anything about a "disabled" value so lets not take this post to an argument about correct syntax, it will not help op as his problem lies elsewhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Chrome and IE has different JavaScript engine, 
Since you only have problem within IE, you could try your code and press F12, then see if there is any error in Console tab, then you could see the problem in code.
 I think the ability to debug is more important than the solution itself.
Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
var com3 = document.forms[0].elements['form1:IncommingOrOutcomming'];
```

With

```
var com3 = document.getElementById('IncommingOrOutcomming');
```